# How to read an Atom XAML File in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In my WPF Application i want to write code to read Atom xaml Feed. There are `Web links` like `www.myweblink/NewXaml.xaml` I want that there my code use this link and get title and description from this xaml file defined in this link.

**ATOM XAML.FILE**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
    <rss version='2.0' xmlns:atom='http://www.w7.org7/Atom'>
    <channelWay>
    <title>Text1 -  Network</title>
    <atom:link href='http://link1/myxaml.xml' rel='self' type='typeOne/rss+xml' />
    <link>http://website.com</link>
    <description> This is New Description </description>
    <lastBuildDate>Fri, 2 Oct 2011 00:00:00 +0500</lastBuildDate>
    <language>en-us</language>
    <item>
    <title>
         My First Title
    </title>
    <link>http://website.com/PageOne.aspx?ID=123790</link>
    <guid>http://website.com/PageTwo.aspx?ID=123790</guid>
    <description>
         My First Description
    </description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 2 Oct 2011 13:10:00 +0500</pubDate>
    </item>
    <item>
    <title>
        My Second Title
     </title>
    <link>
 <link>http://website.com/PageOne1.aspx?ID=123790</link>
    <guid>http://website.com/PageTwo1.aspx?ID=123790</guid>
    <description>
         My Second Description
    </description>
    <pubDate>Fri, 2 Oct 2011 13:10:00 +0500</pubDate>
    </item> . . . . . .
```

**Code To read Xaml File:**

```
 public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FlowDocument content = null;

            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFile.Filter = "FlowDocument Files (*.xaml)|*.xaml|All Files (*.*)|*.*";

            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream xamlFile = openFile.OpenFile() as FileStream;
                if (xamlFile == null) return;
                else
                {   
                    try 
                    { 
                        content = XamlReader.Load(xamlFile) as FlowDocument; 
                        if (content == null) 
                            throw(new XamlParseException("The specified file could not be loaded as a FlowDocument."));
                    }
                    catch (XamlParseException e)
                    {
                        String error = "There was a problem parsing the specified file:\n\n";
                        error += openFile.FileName;
                        error += "\n\nException details:\n\n";
                        error += e.Message;
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(error);
                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        String error = "There was a problem loading the specified file:\n\n";
                        error += openFile.FileName;
                        error += "\n\nException details:\n\n";
                        error += e.Message;
                        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(error);
                        return;
                    }

                    FlowDocRdr.Document = content;
                }
        }
```

Error: It Generates Error that `rss` in Xaml filde is invalid.

Q1: How Can i get title and description from this xaml file?

Q2: I want my  program to go to this link automatically instead of this that i have to save this file on my PC and to give it's path to this code to make it hard coded.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Are you _sure_ that this is a valid flow document _XAML_ file? Looks for like an Atom _XML_ feed to me.

Comment: @Gusdor oh yes it is . I apologize i forget to mention this :( --

Comment: You should probably revise your references to XAML. There is no xaml file here.

Comment: @Gusdor i am new to C#. The code at top has xaml code i want to read. Can you please help me to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gusdor is right, i think too that you are talking about `Atom XML Feed`. 
Here are detailed article related to `XML Feed`
[Article1](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RSSAtomFeed.aspx), 
[Article2](http://www.mnot.net/rss/tutorial/)

Please read these articles. These are really helpful to understand basics of `RSS` and `SyndicationFeed`.

Here Code is:

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"http://link1/myxaml.xml");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
var titles = from item in feed.Items
            select new
                {
                item.Title.Text,  
                 };
var descriptions = from item in feed.Items
        select new
            {   
            item.Summary.Text

             };

foreach (var t in titles)
 {
title_textbox.Text += t.Text + "  ";             //Your All Titles Here

 }
foreach (var des in descriptions)
 {
description_textbox.Text += des.Text + "  ";     //Your All Descriptions Here  
 }
```

Comment: Thank's Buddy:) I need this

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to use an XML parser. Like `XDocument` in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace

```
FileStream xamlFile = openFile.OpenFile() as FileStream;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(xamlFile);

//get title
string title = xdoc.Element("Title").Value;

//get description of first link
string firstLinkDesc = xdoc.Element("Link").Element("Description").Value;
```

Note - I believe you are confused about the relationship of XAML and XML - they are distinct formats. XAML is based upon XML. Atom is a format for delivering feeds that is also based upon XML.

Comment: Thank you but how to add link :(

Comment: @user2835256 there was enough here to expand your horizons, engage brain and work a little out for yourself ;)