# How to read Atom Feed Xml in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, rss

Last Time i posted my question here:  [How to read an Atom XAML File in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588628/how-to-read-an-atom-xaml-file-in-wpf/19590934#19590934)  .It was related to `How to Read Atom Xaml`. One StackOverflow User posted answer that worked. But how to  read a rss/feed having `username` or `password` or having no extension with `.xml`?

Here Code is:

```
 XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"http://link1/myxaml.xml");
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
var titles = from item in feed.Items
            select new
                {
                item.Title.Text,  
                 };
var descriptions = from item in feed.Items
        select new
            {   
            item.Summary.Text

             };

foreach (var t in titles)
 {
title_textbox.Text += t.Text + "  ";             //Your All Titles Here

 }
foreach (var des in descriptions)
 {
description_textbox.Text += des.Text + "  ";     //Your All Descriptions Here  
 }
```

Note: i am using WPF(C#)